# Why the zero address has less balance than the burnt tokens?

Tags: addresses, burn

Currently there are [610,043](https://watchtheburn.com/) burnt ETH, but [address(0)](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) has a balance of 11,277 ETH. Why this zero address has so little Balance if it's a blackhole for all ETH ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETH that is burned is removed from the protocol, not sent to the 0 address. See [here](https://twitter.com/Luit_H/status/1423281752206757894) (twitter thread) and in the [EIP1559 proposal](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559):

> note that the base fee is not given to anyone (it is burned)

Comment: Interesting thread, `"..it happens in the protocol by just removing the balance from the sender and not adding it to the miners balance"`
SO It's not that they explicitly do something to burn them, but the opposite, just remove them from the balance and forget about them.